# Validating input in C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
double input2;
cout<<"please enter one number:"<<endl;
cin>>input2;
```

How can I judge if the user input only about digits, like '3', '4', or '4.241'. Sometimes when users enter a character like 'n', '3.q', my program will crash.

Comment: Have a look at this Question it is similar to yours
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545907/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-input-validation-in-c-with-cin

Answer (score 2):

You can use stringstream to convert a string safely to number:

```
 string input;
 int mynumber;    
 cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
 getline(cin, input);

   // This code converts from string to number safely.
   stringstream myStream(input);
   if (myStream >> myNumber)
    cout <<"number is valid"<<endl;
   else
    cout<<"invalid number";
```

Comment: you can find this code at this link on official cplusplus reference site:

Answer (score 1):

`cin::<<` operator returns `NULL` if operation went bad. Causes may be many but if interpretation fails then the `failbit` is set. You can check it with `rdstate()`:

```
int main()
{
  double input2;
  cout<<"please enter one number:" << endl;

  cin >> input2;

  if (cin.rdstate() & ifstream::failbit)
     cout << "input badly formatted" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't crash because of that. If the cin >> input2 operation fails because of invalid input, cin is put in an invalid state, but it won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that the input was auccessful

```
if (std::cin >> input2) {
    ...
}
```

..  and if it wasn't deal with the erronous input, e.g.:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();
```